# Use a JavaScript prompt in ASP Gridview Delete Command to store "Reason for Deletion"

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview

I currently have a JavaScript confirm prompt for my delete command in my GridView like so:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton  runat="server" 
            CommandName="Delete" 
            CausesValidation="False" 
            CssClass="adminLinks" 
            NavigateUrl="#" 
            Text="delete"
            OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to DELETE this record?');"/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Then for my delete command, I'm running this update code:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:sqlConnection2 %>"
    DeleteCommand="UPDATE [jeakins].[tbl_submit] SET recycle_bin=1 WHERE [ID] = @ID">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

How can I change this from a confirm box to a prompt box that asks "Reason for Deletion?"  and then use that variable in the `DeleteCommand` to update a delete_reason field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a `confirmDelete` Javascript function which displays the prompt box and stores the reason in a HiddenField if the user clicks <kbd>OK</kbd> but cancels the deletion if he clicks <kbd>Cancel</kbd>.

```
function confirmDelete() {
    var reason = prompt('Why do you want to delete?', '');

    if (reason !== null) {
        document.getElementById('hfDeleteReason').value = reason;
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The HiddenField is added to the markup (outside of the GridView) and `confirmDelete` is called by the LinkButton:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfDeleteReason" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />

<asp:LinkButton  runat="server" OnClientClick="return confirmDelete();" ... />
```

If the user confirms the deletion, you can retrieve the reason from the HiddenField in code-behind:

```
string reason = hfDeleteReason.Value;
```

You then have to adapt the `DeleteCommand` to include the reason entered by the user. It could update the `delete_reason` field with the use of an additional parameter:

```
DeleteCommand="UPDATE [jeakins].[tbl_submit] SET recycle_bin=1, delete_reason = @Reason WHERE [ID] = @ID">
...
<DeleteParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="Reason" Type="String" DefaultValue="" />
</DeleteParameters>
```

which would be set in code-behind:

```
SqlDataSource1.DeleteParameters["Reason"].DefaultValue = hfDeleteReason.Value;
```

Comment: Thanks, are you able to show me how you would adapt the DeleteCommand as well?